# Autograder spec gives error output of large problems but works manually

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm working on this online software engineering class. I'm on the last homework assignment to debug some legacy code. I submitted the homework after passing all my cuke and rspec tests. I ran through it manually a few times too to play with the app (the app is a blogging site - bug was that new/edit categories threw an error). The autograder gave me this output that basically says all the major tests failed:

```
should support creating new categories [50 points] (FAILED)
should support editing existing categories [50 points] (FAILED)
should support editing existing categories [50 points] (FAILED)

Failures:
1) The categories page should support creating new categories [50 points]
Failure/Error: page.search('form[action="/admin/categories/edit"]').size.should == 1
expected: 1
got: 0 (using ==)
# /tmp/rspec20131108-5471-1rm3oh.rb:104:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
# /tmp/rspec20131108-5471-1rm3oh.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
# /tmp/rspec20131108-5471-1rm3oh.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
# lib/graders/rspec_grader/rspec_sandbox.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
# lib/graders/rspec_grader/rspec_sandbox.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
# lib/graders/rspec_grader/rspec_runner.rb:42:in `block in run_rspec'
# lib/graders/rspec_grader/rspec_runner.rb:33:in `run_rspec'
# lib/graders/rspec_grader/rspec_runner.rb:24:in `run'
# lib/graders/rspec_grader/weighted_rspec_grader.rb:6:in `grade!'
# ./lib/graders/rspec_grader/heroku_rspec_grader.rb:11:in `grade!'
# lib/graders/rspec_grader/hw5_grader.rb:13:in `grade!'
# ./grade5:33:in `<main>'
2) The categories page should support editing existing categories [50 points]
Failure/Error: page.search('form[action="/admin/categories/edit"]').size.should == 1
expected: 1
got: 0 (using ==)
# /tmp/rspec20131108-5471-1rm3oh.rb:119:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
# /tmp/rspec20131108-5471-1rm3oh.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
# /tmp/rspec20131108-5471-1rm3oh.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
# lib/graders/rspec_grader/rspec_sandbox.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
# lib/graders/rspec_grader/rspec_sandbox.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
# lib/graders/rspec_grader/rspec_runner.rb:42:in `block in run_rspec'
# lib/graders/rspec_grader/rspec_runner.rb:33:in `run_rspec'
# lib/graders/rspec_grader/rspec_runner.rb:24:in `run'
# lib/graders/rspec_grader/weighted_rspec_grader.rb:6:in `grade!'
# ./lib/graders/rspec_grader/heroku_rspec_grader.rb:11:in `grade!'
# lib/graders/rspec_grader/hw5_grader.rb:13:in `grade!'
# ./grade5:33:in `<main>'
3) The categories page should support editing existing categories [50 points]
Failure/Error: page.search('form[action="/admin/categories/edit"]').size.should == 1
expected: 1
got: 0 (using ==)
# /tmp/rspec20131108-5471-1rm3oh.rb:134:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
# /tmp/rspec20131108-5471-1rm3oh.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
# /tmp/rspec20131108-5471-1rm3oh.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
# lib/graders/rspec_grader/rspec_sandbox.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
# lib/graders/rspec_grader/rspec_sandbox.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
# lib/graders/rspec_grader/rspec_runner.rb:42:in `block in run_rspec'
# lib/graders/rspec_grader/rspec_runner.rb:33:in `run_rspec'
# lib/graders/rspec_grader/rspec_runner.rb:24:in `run'
# lib/graders/rspec_grader/weighted_rspec_grader.rb:6:in `grade!'
# ./lib/graders/rspec_grader/heroku_rspec_grader.rb:11:in `grade!'
# lib/graders/rspec_grader/hw5_grader.rb:13:in `grade!'
# ./grade5:33:in `<main>'
```

Except all my cucumber tests pass and when I run though the app manually, it works just fine. Whether I manually type in the path it's trying to reach or run through it by clicking the buttons, everything renders just fine. Any ideas on why this might be happening? Yes, I am using the admin account whenever I run through this manually and through cucumber (as this is a feature only administrators should access).

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. If there's a file you need to see, just tell me in the comments and I'll add it in. I just have no idea where this error might be. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be an issue with my Ruby version and the autograder's version of Ruby. This is why it worked locally and through my own tests but when it hooked up with the autograder, some very basic tests failed.

Answer (score 0):

The errors state that there is a missing HTML element: a `form` with an `action` attribute of `/admin/categories/edit`. Does your page have an element that matches that?